# Integrate FairPlay Streaming Server SDK (it is in swift) into my existing objective c code using Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode8, objective-c-swift-bridge, fairplay

i try to integrate FairPlay Streaming Server SDK (it is in swift)  into my existing objective c code.using Xcode 8.2.1 project in MAC OSX 10.12.3 system.The FairPlay Streaming Server SDK consists of swift classes that can be imported into objective c code by using bridge file am getting the following errors as shown in image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baIO2.png)

Comment: don't post same question you already tell this question before 1 hour

Comment: you check your old question answer is working or not?s